# Supervisor settings environment variables and getting a Error: Unexpected end of key/value pairs

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

Folks,

I'm trying to move something into a docker container, which means a shift from running it as a daemon into a stand alone process controlled by supervisord.  Now I don't have much experience with supervisord so it's likely a simple configuration error on my part.

The problem stems from that this application needs certain environment variables set.  When running as a daemon I'd set them via a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/
TNS_ADMIN=/home/oracle/app/network/admin
export ORACLE_HOME TNS_ADMIN
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:/home/oracle/app/lib
ncftpd_authd
```

In supervisord.conf I set it up as

```
[program:authd]
environment=ORACLE_HOME="/home/oracle/app/",TNS_ADMIN="/home/oracle/app/network/admin",export ORACLE_HOME TNS_ADMIN,export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PATH:/home/oracle/app/lib"
command=/usr/local/sbin/ncftpd_authd
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
```

However if I call supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf I get an error

```
[root@0d7f9a5d7c3a src]# supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf 
Error: Unexpected end of key/value pairs
```

I believe it's related to environment line as if I comment that out supervisord will start (but the authd won't run).  What am I doing wrong in setting up the environment in the supervisord conf file?

Comment: You don't (I think) want the `export`s in that line. Change it to just a list of `name=value`.

Answer (score 3):

`environment` should be a list of key/value pairs, which means that it shouldn't contain `export`. The correct value would be:

```
environment=ORACLE_HOME="/home/oracle/app/",TNS_ADMIN="/home/oracle/app/network/admin",LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PATH:/home/oracle/app/lib"
```

You may also need to replace `$PATH` by its value. Or, you can follow the standard of writing variable from outside in http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=environment. In short, to use `$PATH`, just write `%(ENV_PATH)s`. Then, it would be like this:

```
environment=ORACLE_HOME="/home/oracle/app/",TNS_ADMIN="/home/oracle/app/network/admin",LD_LIBRARY_PATH="%(ENV_PATH)s:/home/oracle/app/lib"
```